# Standard practice for working with user uploaded files in an asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

This is the first time I am building a web app for the sole purpose of processing user uploaded files and I have a few questions in regards to how this is normally done:

1. Are there any security issues that I have to take into account? The files to be processed are in essence text files that my app will read line by line. Should I limit the file upload extension and/or is there any other precautions I should take into account?
2. What is the best organization method for uploaded files? These files do not need to be stored permanently in my app so should I just dump them in a general "Data" folder and delete whatever is no longer needed?
3. Are there any other important aspects to building web apps with similar functionalities that I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: Whats there to organise if you dont need to store the files? Just read the stream, process it and discard. No need to actually save the file if you dont need to.

Comment: @Jamiec I wasn't aware you could do this. Are you saying the file is read client side and the data is send to the server? How might you do this?

Comment: @Tony the file is read & sent by the browser to the server. You can read the stream if you want to in-memory and then just throw it away when you're done with it. Depending on your traffic, this may put a strain on the server, though. Saving the files to disk is definitely slower but it uses fewer resources at a given time and you can delay processing if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The only security issue you have to watch for is inserting the raw text (without data scrubbing to prevent SQL injections) into the database. If there is no database involved, you should be fine. As for extensions, limiting extensions is really a poor top-level filter. It's good to have, but it's only peering skin deep into what the file really contains. A file size limit would help also.
2. Saving to the disk can be costly with a large amount of transactions, but on the other hand, it will clutter your server memory less as more requests/more threads are being used. You can also work with the files in-memory, but for large files, it may end up being detrimental. Consider what you're working with and choose the best approach.
3. Define a timeout so that large uploaded files won't be occupying unnecessary server processes when in the end it's too large anyway.

I am assuming that you're working with ASP.NET's `FileUpload` control. Bear in mind that the file does not persist through postbacks (to prevent a security loophole), so the user has to keep browsing to the file each time the page is requested. This is a nuisance if you have server-side validators.

---

*Edited to answer comment:*

By working in-memory, I am talking about manipulating the file uploaded purely through code without resorting to saving it physically on the server's disk.

For instance, if you're using a `FileUpload` control, then the user's file can be accessed through a Stream object `FileUpload.FileContent` or as a byte array `FileUpload.FileBytes` ([API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx)). Since that's a `Stream` you can just read the file on the fly without having to save it first.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadControl" ToolTip="Upload a file" runat="server" />
```

**Codebehind:**

```
If fileUploadControl.HasFile AndAlso _
   (fileUploadControl.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt") OrElse _
    fileUploadControl.ToLower().FileName.EndsWith(".dat")) Then
    SaveThisToDataBase(fileUploadControl.FileName, fileUploadControl.FileBytes)
End If
```

See? No need to save to the disk at all. `fileUploadControl.FileBytes` contains a bytearray of the data uploaded.

If you wanted to save to a file, then you can just use the stream to write to the disk.

Comment: My database queries are parameterized so injections should be okay. The files are relatively small but I'm not familiar with what you mean by working with the files in-memory. Do you have any examples or references to link to?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how 'standard' my answer is but here's what I did when I had a similar setup:

- I limited the file extensions to a handful of file types, just to make it harder to upload bad files. It's easy to circumvent but at least it's one more step a malicious user would have to take.
- I had to add write permissions to the IUSR account under IIS to the folder where I stored the files. This folder was a subfolder of my application's root folder.
- I had to deal with a lot of files so I created a new subfolder for each month, like `Uploaded\012012`, `Uploaded\022012`, etc. This made file access faster since I only had a few hundred files in each folder. I stored each upload in the database and had a scheduled task to clean up the file system regularly. This also deleted old empty folders.

As I said, I don't know if this is standard (or even if it's a really good practice), but it worked well for the environment where I used it.